# Adding dynamic routes to node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create a generic route which will be capable of accepting different combinations of user id and token.I understand the route is capable of accepting generic expressions.

It should work for /user1/token123 ,also for /user2/token234 etc.I do not know how to define it. I tried /{user}/{token}. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
app.get('/:user/:token', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

More info here: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param

Comment: this doesn't render the CSS file !!

Answer (score 0):

Use ":" in your routes.

Example :

```
    app.get('/:user/:token', function(req,res){
      var user = req.params.user;
      var token req.params.token;
    });
```